# app engine post to twitter

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter

I want to build an app engine project that posts to a single pre-defined twitter account. I do not have any problem of including username and password hard coded inside the app. This is normally supposed to be just a post request + authentication. My question can I achieve this using simple http authentication instead of oauth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter has stopped supporting basic auth long time ago...

Please see this Twitter developers documentation about [Moving from Basic Auth to OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/moving-from-basic-auth-to-oauth).

Comment: You can read [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq) that Basic Auth was unsupported officially as of August 16, 2010.

Comment: I used AppEngine-OAuth librayr and it just worked. I was able to cut the corner for my specfic case. After I created a new app in my twitter account, it gave me oauth tokes for my account (for testing purposes). Since I only needed to post to this account, I just hardcoded this token in to my app.